# Display the choices even if no rows found in associated table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have the following 3 tables for a small voting/polling feature:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `options` (
  `option_id` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `poll_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `option` tinytext NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `option_id_poll_id` (`option_id`,`poll_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Storing poll options/choices';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `poll_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `question` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `dated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`poll_id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Table to store poll questions/titles';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `poll_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `option_id` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `dated` datetime NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `poll_id_nick` (`poll_id`,`nick`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and I'm fetching the results of a certain `poll_id` (represented with `%d` below) using the following query:

```
SELECT
    o.option_id AS option_id,
    o.`option` AS `option`,
    COUNT(v.nick) AS total
FROM options o
LEFT JOIN votes v
    USING (poll_id)
WHERE o.poll_id = %d
    AND v.option_id = o.option_id
ORDER BY total DESC, o.option_id ASC
```

A sample can be seen on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a073/1). I'd like to retrieve all the options/choices available for any `poll_id` and display the `COUNT` as `0`, or `NULL`; if no user chose that particular option. Thus, for the fiddle example, the result would be:

```
option_id | option | total
1         |   A    |   3
2         |   B    |   1
3         |   C    |   0
```

Comment: Remove the `AND v.option_id = o.option_id`. It shouldn't be there anyway, as the `USING` does the join. You also need to add `GROUP BY o.option_id`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a073/6 - "v.option_id = o.option_id" is supposed to be part of join condition so use ON instead of USING and move it there - when it is in WHERE, it works "after" the LEFT of join, so for not existing matches it is never true. And the group by per @ypercube is needed too.

Comment: @user1786423 Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I did, would you suggest adding something more in there? Like this it seems bit short as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a073/6 - "v.option_id = o.option_id" is supposed to be part of join condition so use ON instead of USING and move it there - when it is in WHERE, it works "after" the LEFT of join, so for not existing matches it is never true. And the group by per @ypercube is needed too.

Comment: Is there someway to get the percentage of total votes, instead of the number of votes?

Comment: You need total of all rows for that - to get it you can use either separate query and store it to variable, use subquery (mysql 5.6 should be able to cache it for better performance instead of recomputing for each row) and divide with it  - those two will let you compute it in mysql directly. Or you compute percentage in application, then either summing all rows gives you total, or you can use [WITH ROLLUP modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and mysql can compute total for you in the same query - but you still have to use it in app to get percentages.

Comment: I'm doing it as shown here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/90249/12240

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e913e/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e913e/4 show howyou do it with subquery and how to do it with variable, you can click "show execution plan" to view query explain.
I would not use %d, that gives possibility of sql injection or at least errors in sql, use integer placeholder to be sure you always put number in there, and cast your params to number in application. And try to think about if you really want MyISAM engine (I prefer InnoDB, but you maybe have some reasons..)